# MSSQL ERROR "Invalid object name" when I add a field to the query?

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

I have an INSERT query that works fine, but when I add an extra field I get the oh-so-helpful:

> Invalid object name 'optimizations'

Optimizations being the table name. The query is below... I am totally lost as to why this wouldn't work. If I cut & paste the query into MSSQL Management Studio, the query works fine.

```
INSERT INTO [optimizations] 
    ([opt_date],[opt_concept_id],[opt_pallet],[opt_turnable],
     [opt_sideupok],[opt_endupok],[opt_flatok],[opt_notstickingout],
     [opt_notinoverhang],[opt_itemsloaded],[opt_loadedweight],
     [opt_pweightutil],[opt_pvolumeutil],[opt_request_xml],
     [opt_response_xml],[opt_images],[opt_primary_stage_id]) 
VALUES 
     (GETDATE(),'775','20ft','true','false','false','true',
      'true','true','10','5952.6','18.6','48.9',
      '<xml><herpa><derpa>xml</derpa></herpa></xml>',
      '<xml><herpa><derpa>xml</derpa></herpa></xml>',
      'img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg','98');
```

For some reason, if I include the last field in the query `[opt_primary_stage_id]` it does not work... if I omit this field it works fine. Interestingly enough if I add `[opt_primary_stage_id]` to the list of fields being passed, and pass it a value of `NULL` the query also works fine. The `[opt_primary_stage_id]` field's data type is `INT`, I have tried including the last entry of the `VALUES()` section both as a straight number (`3`) and with quotes (`'3'`)... neither works.

The server executing the code is running PHP 4.3.9, under IIS and with and MSSQL.

This is a version of the query, with the SAME data that will work.

```
INSERT INTO [optimizations] 
    ([opt_date],[opt_concept_id],[opt_pallet],[opt_turnable],
     [opt_sideupok],[opt_endupok],[opt_flatok],[opt_notstickingout],
     [opt_notinoverhang],[opt_itemsloaded],[opt_loadedweight],
     [opt_pweightutil],[opt_pvolumeutil],[opt_request_xml],
     [opt_response_xml],[opt_images])
VALUES 
     (GETDATE(),'775','20ft','true','false','false','true','true',
      'true','10','5952.6','18.6','48.9',
      '<xml><herpa><derpa>xml</derpa></herpa></xml>',
      '<xml><herpa><derpa>xml</derpa></herpa></xml>',
      'img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg');
```

EDIT: Fixed XML to have proper bracketing & added working query.

Comment: I haven't an answer, sorry, but your two XML examples have a missing ">" after "</derpa", FWIW.

Comment: any triggers we should know about?

Comment: I am confused whether this is the successful query or the failing query. [opt_primary_stage_id] is already part of the query, so if you are adding it again, that could be the problem.

Comment: @oddthinking there is a LOT more XML in the actual query, I cut it down for simplicity's sake. The query displayed above is the one that's failing... when PHP executes the above query I get the invalid object name error. If I pass the same exact query a NULL value for [opt_primary_stage_id]

Comment: could you post the previous working query?

Comment: @servermanfail no triggers, just a single insert query

Comment: @changokun I just added the working version

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler (or a free alternative like [AnjLab SQL Profiler](http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler) if you are using the express edition) to capture the **actual** query being executed - it may be different / have been altered before being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a field **won't** cause failure on it's own: there *is* a valid reason.

You say it runs in SSMS OK then it shows that issue is in PHP or in the call.

First thoughts:

- How long is the command. Is it being truncated somewhere in PHP? Is this dynamic SQL IRL?
- Is the user context the same from the client? You may have the same table in 2 different schemas for example, with differing permissions.
- Wrong database in the connection. What does SELECT DB_NAME() say? Sounds obvious but no object = not there. Don't dismiss this idea and assume it is the correct context: check.

Comment: This *was* dynamic SQL... but I was printing the SQL out so I could inspect it at runtime before it got executed. What would fail when it ran would run fine when copy/pasted into SSMS. The context is the same, there is only 1 database and 1 table that it could possibly be interacting with... but there ARE two different users. I would accept this as a plausible reason if the query didn't work when I passed the field a NULL value. Thanks for the help though... I think this is just one of those things I will never truly understand.

Comment: Ok, so at first I ran over the solutions you presented... the one that finally clicked was the suggestion to run SELECT DB_NAME(). BINGO! **There was a different database/connection attempting to be written to!** The ACTUAL problem is that when I did my include for the DB connection... _I used include_once instead of just include_. Because the DB connection I needed had previously been included once... it skipped it and left it with the previous DB context. GBN, you the man!